# light and shadows Opentk in VB net

Tags: vb.net, shader, opentk, light

Hi I have create a simple project to show few little qube, now I try to insert light, I have tryed few examples founded on line but right now I can only "switch" light a stron light everyware or a little light far on Z direction I can't move the position of light.

this is my code:

```
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit)
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit)

    Dim perspective As Matrix4

    Dim xmin As Single = -200
    Dim ymin As Single = -200
    Dim xmax As Single = 300
    Dim ymax As Single = 300
    Dim size As Single = xmax - xmin
    Dim rate As Single = GlControl1.Width / GlControl1.Height

    ymax = ymin + (size / rate)

    perspective = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, -1000, 1000)


    'Perspective
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection) 'load the camera
    GL.LoadIdentity()
    GL.LoadMatrix(perspective)

    GL.Viewport(0, 0, GlControl1.Width, GlControl1.Height)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest)
    GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Less)


    GL.Enable(EnableCap.ColorMaterial)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Light0)

    Dim cl0() As Single = {NumericUpDown4.Value, NumericUpDown5.Value, NumericUpDown6.Value, NumericUpDown7.Value}
    GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Position, cl0)




    GL.Rotate(NumericUpDown3.Value, New Vector3(1, 0, 0)) 'asse X
    GL.Rotate(NumericUpDown2.Value, New Vector3(0, 1, 0)) 'asse Y
    GL.Rotate(NumericUpDown1.Value, New Vector3(0, 0, 1)) 'asse Z

    For x = -100 To 100 Step 20
        For y = -100 To 100 Step 20
            For z = -100 To 100 Step 20
                drawCube(x, y, z, 5)
            Next
        Next
    Next


    'Finally..................
    GraphicsContext.CurrentContext.VSync = True ' to syncronize with the GPU ability
    GlControl1.SwapBuffers() 'takes from GL and put to control
    GlControl1.Invalidate()
```

I have obtain someting only with variation of #3 and #4 value on cl0 array, example:
if cl0 array is (0,0,1,0) I obtain this:
[0010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzs6S.png)
if cl0 array is (0,0,0,1) or (0,0,1,1) I obtain this:
[0001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toGBZ.png)

I have also try with many other value and nothing change.
How can I set the position X,Y,Z of light?
And, How can I start the shadows?

Comment: Most likely the the effect is related to the [Gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) of the [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) light model. This technology is deprecated  for decades. Nowadays the light is computed per fragment in the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader).